# React Navigation 5 - Native Stack Navigator with custom header which has a searchbar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I'm currently in a project for which we are using React Navigation 5 with the native stack navigator due to its increased performance. We are needing to add a searchbar to the header cause the client isn't gonna like it to be somewhere else. Is there any way to make a custom header?
using **options={{ headerShown: false }}** is not an option cause inside the native stack navigator we have a bottom stack navigator and inside this bottom tab navigator we have a top stack navigator with the screens inside it. So using **headerShown: false** and a custom header inside the screens would only render it below the top tabs and that would not be acceptable.
Any ideas on how to make this? is using the common stack navigator with a custom react element as the **header** prop the only solution?

Greatly appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: if you show us the structure of the navigators in a hierarchy style we will understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using the headerRight option and passing it a full custom header component.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html
You can pass in `header` to the `options` prop and use a custom header.

Answer (score 0):

pass `navigationOptions` in your component

```js
export default class Test extends Component{

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: "Test",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: #f1f1f1,
          elevation: 0
        },
        headerTintColor: "#000",
      });

    render(){
        return(<View><Text>Test App</Text></View>);
    }
}
```